# Accessing a file pointer in a dynamically created object after the objects deletion

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm been scratching my head trying to figure out if this is possible (safe!).

I have a struct containing a file pointer:

```
struct s {
    FILE *fp;
};
```

I create a function that uses 'fopen' to open a file and set that pointer to a dynamically created object of s:

```
s* openFile() {
    s *pointer = new s{ fopen("someFile.txt", "r") };
    return pointer;
}
```

In my main function I call 'openFile' and set the a local 'FILE' pointer to the same address pointer to by 's->fp':

```
int main() {
    s *pointer = openFile();
    FILE* fp = pointer->fp;
    delete pointer;

    // will fp still be valid to access here
    // use fp in some way
    
    fclose(fp);
}
```

### My questions:

- Will fp still be usable after the deletion of the object?
- I need many return types for my actual function implementation and one of these return types are a file pointer, hence why I created a struct (it houses all my return types). Is there a better way?
- How does one test implementations such as this?

### My thoughts thus far:

- the pointer created by 'fopen' can be returned from functions, indicating that memory is allocated to be valid outside outside the function
- 'fclose' is needed to properly end the used of the file pointer
- it should work and be safe (no undefined behavior) since memory location is still allocated and not freed

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What would you say if the member of `s` were an `int`?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way: use `std::ifstream` because, after all, this is C++.

Comment: Your struct `s` doesn't respect [rule of 5/3/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)...

Answer (score 0):

> Will fp still be usable after the deletion of the object?

Yes. `fp` is just a pointer -- it's just a variable that contains a memory address. Freeing the structure containing the pointer itself does not free the object that was pointed to (unless of course you specifically deallocate the object in your structure's destructor, which you're not).

`pointer` and `pointer->fp` will no longer be valid, but your stored `fp` will.

> I need many return types for my actual function implementation and one of these return types are a file pointer, hence why I created a struct (it houses all my return types). Is there a better way?

Probably, but it depends on what you are doing. Having a structure that contains all the return types will *work*, but yes there is probably a better way. Unfortunately, I can't give any specific advice without a more detailed description of your project, and even then it would just be my opinion.

> How does one test implementations such as this?

This is a very broad question, but you might be interested in something like [unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). Good documentation with stated preconditions, postconditions, and invariants can also help in the testing process.

But there are too many ways to test code for me to be able to answer that here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `fp` should still be valid. A stdio `FILE` pointer is valid until you call `fclose()` on it. `fopen()` typically allocates the memory dynamically (although standard streams like `stdin` and `stdout` may point to static data for optimization).

You could define a destructor in `struct s` that calls `fclose(this.fp)`. In that case, `fp` would become invalid after `delete pointer`. If you really want to encapsulate a stdio stream in a C++ object, this is probably what you should do.